# Display Multiple Symbols for a single point feature by field attribute vale

Tags: qgis, symbology, fields-attributes, select-by-attribute, display

I want to create a point feature layer and add points. 
Around the point I'd like to add icons/symbols and labels based on data in fields of an attribute table.[image: Example of Fields with and attribute table (fig.2)][image: Point Feature with icons/symbols and layers (fig.1)]

Comment: A workaround would be to create one point for each attribute and then use point displacement as grid.
But having a solution for your way would be more elegant of course.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can work with a rule based symbology and use different displacemet values for each symbol in your rules, like in the attached image:

[image]

With some more work, you can add some datadefinded overrides for the displacement, for example: if phone=0 then change the y-displacement of the parking-symbol to 0 to avoid gaps like in the above image:

```
if ("phone"=0, '4,0','4,5')
```

[image]

for the callout labels you should use a geometry generator symbol, just search this forum for qgis and callout label